# Two different table counts insert into Hive Table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

i need to insert data into hive table from two different table counts.

example, let assume i have a table `sample` having fields `counter1` and `counter2`

now i have another two tables `test1` and `test2`.

i need to insert into `sample.counter1 as select count(*) from test1` and `sample.counter2 as select count(*) from test2`

it works if final table is having one column like:

```
insert into table sample select count(*) from test1
```

now i need to insert two columns.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
insert into sample.counter1 (counter1, counter2)
    select t1.cnt, t2.cnt
    from (select count(*) as cnt from test1) t1 cross join
         (select count(*) as cnt from test2) t2;
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, working !, any idea if i have another string column and what will be the query?

Comment: @SatishKaruturi . . . You can add a constant value to the `SELECT`.  If that doesn't answer your question, Youshould ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.